# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to store data into database from my form.I have try below code,but it will give me fatal error.what is the changes i have to do so that code can work fine.Here i have check my database connection all working fine but there is only one error of fatal error:Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object.

```
<?php

        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {

        $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '','tmtool');
            if($conn -> connect_errno )
            {
              die('coudn\'t connect to the database' . mysqli_connect_error());
            }
            if(! get_magic_quotes_gpc() )
            {
               $Testcase_id = addslashes (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Testcase_id'));
               $Testcase_title = addslashes (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Testcase_title'));
               $Testcase_desc = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Testcase_desc'));
               $Product_id= addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Project_id'));
               $Date_created=  addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Date_created'));
               $Created_by=  addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Created_by'));
               $Type=  addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Type'));
               $Priority = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Priority'));
               $Precondition=  addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Precondition'));
               $Test_step = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Test_step'));
               $Expected_result = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Expected_result'));
               $Request_mode = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Request_mode'));
               $Language = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Language'));
               $Category = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Category'));
               $Sub_category = addslashes(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Sub_category'));

            }
            else
            {

               $Testcase_id =(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Testcase_id'));
               $Testcase_title =(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Testcase_title'));
               $Testcase_desc = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Testcase_desc'));
               $Product_id=(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Project_id'));
               $Date_created=(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Date_created'));
               $Created_by=(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Created_by'));
               $Type= (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Type'));
               $Priority =(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Priority'));
               $Precondition=(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Precondition'));
               $Test_step =(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Test_step'));
               $Expected_result =(filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Expected_result'));
               $Request_mode = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Request_mode'));
               $Language = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Language'));
               $Category = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Category'));
               $Sub_category = (filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Sub_category'));
            }






        $sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tmtool.testcase_master ( `Testcase_id`,`Testcase_title`,`Testcase_desc`,`Product_id`,`Date_created`,`Created_by`,`Type`,`Priority`, `Precondition`, `Test_step`, `Expected_result`, `Request_mode`, `Language`, `Category`, `Sub_category`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
        $sql->bind_param('sssssssssssssss',$Testcase_id,$Testcase_title,$Testcase_desc, $Product_id, $Date_created, $Created_by, $Type , $Priority, $Precondition, $Test_step, $Expected_result, $Request_mode, $Language, $Category , $Sub_category);

            if($sql->execute())
            {
                echo "Entered data successfully\n";
                mysqli_close($conn);

            }
            else {

              die('Could not enter data: ' . mysqli_error($conn));
            }    
          }else{
              echo "you are not able to connect to data base";
        }
        ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use [`mysqli_*`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php) in OOP style so you have to use the keyword `new` and remove the `_connect`part for the connection like this:

```
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '','tmtool');
      //^^^       ^ '_connect' removed
      //| See here
```

Also change your close statement from:

```
mysqli_close($conn);
```

to this:

```
$conn->close();
```

And for errors you have to use this:

```
$conn->error  //Not mysqli_error($conn)
```

Comment: if i make those change then it will give me this error Fatal error: Class 'mysqli_connect' not found

Comment: @TrilokPatel Ah my mistake, you also have to remove the `_connect` part, totally forgot that

Comment: @TrilokPatel mysqli_connect not found or what?

Comment: no Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object this error

Comment: @TrilokPatel That means that your prepare statement returns false. Please check if all column names are correct and also maybe try to but back ticks `\`` around the table name e.g. `INSERT INTO \`tmtool\`.\`testcase_master\``

Comment: I have checked all the fields name and also change what ever you suggest @Rizier123 but still same error....

Comment: @TrilokPatel You can put the entire prepare statement in a if block and check if it fails, which it does, but I don't see anything wrong! (e.g. `if($sql = $conn->pre...) echo "fail";`) Also please update your question with the table structure

Comment: @TrilokPatel Also please update your question with the code which you use now and test your query with some test data in your input query and tell me if it works

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Rizier123,
When i am try to put prepare statement into if condition then it will work for me...Thanks @Rizier123

Final correction in code is:

```
        if(($sql = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO tmtool.testcase_master ( `Testcase_id`,`Testcase_title`,`Testcase_desc`,`Product_id`,`Date_created`,`Created_by`,`Subscriber_type`,`Priority`, `Precondition`, `Test_step`, `Expected_result`, `Activation_mode`, `Language`, `Category`, `Sub_category`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"))== FALSE)
        {
            echo "false";

        }        
        $sql->bind_param('sssssssssssssss',$Testcase_id,$Testcase_title,$Testcase_desc, $Product_id, $Date_created, $Created_by, $Subscriber_type , $Priority, $Precondition, $Test_step, $Expected_result, $Activation_mode, $Language, $Category , $Sub_category);
```